# ASP.NET Core 3.1: MapControllers

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an asp.net web application with a controller and some views. I'm trying to access this view in my browser but am getting 404 error. I have a UserRolesController in a main folder called Controllers and my view is in the Views/UserRoles/Index.cshtml folder. My startup.cs has the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
            
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }            

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

When I navigate to localhost:5001/UserRoles, I'm getting a 404 error.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added MVC support(with quite a few features) and it started working. Courtesy: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/difference-between-addmvc-and-addmvccore-method/